# Tkinter Text widget - identify line by y-coord

Tags: python, events, tkinter, textarea

is there any method to identify row/column in `tkinter.Text` widget in `tkinter`? I mean something like methods `identify_row(event.y)` and `identify_column(event.x)`.

I want to highlight the line bellow cursor and I need it to work with **disabled** Text widget.

I was thinking of getting the height and count the line number from the current y coord and the height of the line, but I thought, there might be a better way.

So, is there?
Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, it works for me:

```
def __onLClicked(self, event):
    linestart = self.index("@{0},{1} linestart".format(event.x, event.y))
    lineend = self.index("{} lineend".format(linestart))

    self.tag_remove("current_line", 1.0, "end")
    self.tag_add("current_line", linestart, lineend)
```

Only one detail, it unfortunately doesn't higlight all lines the same, because each line has different length. If anyone knows how to highlight full 'width' (the length of the longes line I guess) for every line without adding extra spaces...that'd be great!

Comment: to highlight the full line, include the trailing newline when adding the tag. For instance, you can use `"{} lineend+1c".format(linestart)`